# Retrieve markdown document structure (with pandoc?)

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I have a set of `md` documents written by a group of people. Each `md` file is a characterization/description of an object and has identical structure (sections, each section with identical title). You can think of it as a form written in Markdown.

Each file looks something like:

```
# Object "foobar"

## Color

The object is red with pink dots.    

## Shape

Square-like    

## Texture

Smooth like a glass.
```

and, say, `snafoo.md`:

```
# Object "snafoo"

## Color

The object is green with black stripes.    

## Shape

Ball-like

## Texture

Rough. A bit like sandpaper.
```

and so on...

I would like to automatically "merge" these files so that content of matching sections is concatenated. Based on the two files above the I would like to get an output like:

```
# Color

The object is red with pink dots.    

The object is green with black stripes.    

# Shape

Square-like

Ball-like

# Texture

Smooth like a glass.

Rough. A bit like sandpaper.
```

What I found to be useful is to use `pandoc` to convert `md` file to a `docbook` format, which is essentially an XML-like format so it is easy to parse it and retrieve the structure using existing XML tools. OPML output seems a good candidate too.

I think either docbook or OPML would be acceptable. I would write a script that merges the appropriate sections (appends their content from different documents).

However, `pandoc` translates all the special characters to HTML codes like `&quot;`, `&amp` and so on. What I would like is to be able to extract, say, specific subsections in the hierarchy but have the text (e.g. body of a subsection) exactly as it is in the original `md` file. How would you convert the HTML codes (`&quot;` etc.) back to ASCII so that everything can be rendered to PDF/DOC/... with `pandoc`?

Comment: In every XML-based format that has nested tags, some characters (especially `>` and `<`) are required to be escaped. Maybe you should tell us more about your use case...

Comment: I elaborated a bit and added an example.

Answer (score 2):

Pandoc is written in Haskell and uses a Haskell data structure as an intermediate format for converting documents. You can choose `native` as output format to get that data structure. Haskell data structures are very easy to parse. You can also just use Haskell and `read` the data structure using the types from the pandoc package, or use the document reader functions from pandoc directly.

Comment: Thanks. JSON and `native` look too messy to me for this purpose. But it is good to know anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Two other candidates for output formats to check might be

- JSON, use one of the many JSON viewers
- OPML (Outline Processor Markup Language) an XML format

Comment: Indeed. I tried OPML and it is close to docboox for my purpose. How would you go about converting HTML codes to original ASCII?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit? The best way to do it to add an 'Edit' heading to the original question and extend your question. What do you mean by 'converting HTML to original ASCII'?

Comment: I added some examples. By "converting" I meant after you use `pandoc` to convert `md` to `docbook` I'm getting, say, `&amp;` instead of `&` and so on. Then I can write the script that merges the sections extracted from `docbook` format. Then I would like to take this merged `docbook` and convert it to `md` again. I hope it is more clear now.